# Angular mat-paginator displaying full async dataSource

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material-table, mat-pagination

I would expect i'm missing something obvious here, and I would appreciate any support or insight provided...

I have this mat-table

component.html

```
  <mat-paginator></mat-paginator>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="ds" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> MetaverseID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="totalLots">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total lots </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.totalLots}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="investment">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Investment </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.investment}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="investmentValue">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Investment Value </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.investmentValue}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="mvShare">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Metaverse Share </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mvShare}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="valueIndex">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value Index </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.valueIndex}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

which goes with this typsescript file

component.ts

```
imports...
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-dataset',
  templateUrl: './main-dataset.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-dataset.component.scss']
})
export class MainDatasetComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'totalLots', 'investment', 'investmentValue', 'mvShare', 'valueIndex'];
  
  constructor() { }

  @Input() owners: { [key: string]: MVLot[] } = {};

  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) pag: MatPaginator;

  output: OutputRecord[] = []
  ds = new MatTableDataSource<any>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ddSelect(target: any) {
    if ("the right dropdown value is selected") {
      this.valueSet = true;

      this.ids.forEach(w => {

        // some finessing logic

        this.output.push(out);
        
      });

      this.output.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.totalLots - a.totalLots;
      });


      this.ds.paginator = this.pag;
      this.ds = new MatTableDataSource(this.output);
    }

    if (this.valueSet) {
      this.valueSet = false;
    }
  }
}
```

it feels like there's something missing connecting the table to the pagination element.

The datasource element isn't populated until the user has selected a value in the dropdown. The page loads the table, but pagination never seems to acknowledge the changes.

[image]

The end result is that the pagination control seems to have no connection to the table.
I imagine somewhere in the mat-table lib these two elements are linked, since i didn't see any reference to this in the mat-talbe documentation.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

What am I missing that creates this disconnect between these two controls? Is it a problem that my data is populated after initial page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, I was able to get this working using this code:

```
[other imports...]
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-dataset',
  templateUrl: './main-dataset.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-dataset.component.scss'],
})

export class MainDatasetComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

  allLandsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<OutputRecord>(this.output);
  openLotsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MVLot>(this.openLots);

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
    this.allLandsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.output);
    this.openLotsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.openLots);
  }

  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.allLandsDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.allLandsDataSource.sort = this.sort;

    this.openLotsDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.openLotsDataSource.sort = this.sort;

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  ddSelect(target: any) {
        if (this.wallets.length > 0) {
          if (!this.whaleTableDefined) {
            this.whaleTableDefined = true;
      
            this.wallets.forEach(w => {
              [some logic]
              this.output.push(out);
              
            });
      
            this.output.sort(function (a, b) {
              return b.totalLots - a.totalLots;
            });
          }
      
          this.allLandsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.output);
          this.allLandsDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        }
    

  }
}
```

By setting paginator on the dataSource after, this worked.

Comment: Looking back at this, in the first blocks of code, immediately after I set my pag component, I was overwriting my datasource object. Which is likely why I wasn't getting the pagination element.

Solutions are usually obvious, if you just look with a different perspective.